# Difference between Arrays.asList(array) and new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(array))

Tags: java, list, collections

What is the difference between

- `List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(ia));  // Copy`
- `List<Integer> list2 = Arrays.asList(ia);`

, where `ia` is an array of integers?

I came to know that some operations are not allowed in `list2`. Why is it so?
How is it stored in memory (references / copy)?

When I shuffle the lists, `list1` doesn't affect the original array, but `list2` does. But still `list2` is somewhat confusing.

How does `ArrayList` being upcasted to list differ from creating a new `ArrayList`?

```
list1 differs from (1)
ArrayList<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(ia));
```

Comment: I suggest you look after [Google Guava's](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html) option.
`Lists.newArrayList(ia)` makes an independent copy, just as the first option. It is simply more general and better to look at.

Answer (score 257, accepted):

1. First, let's see what this does:

   ```
   Arrays.asList(ia)
   ```

   It takes an array `ia` and creates a wrapper that implements `List<Integer>`, which makes the original array available as a list. Nothing is copied and all, only a single wrapper object is created. Operations on the list wrapper are propagated to the original array. This means that if you shuffle the list wrapper, the original array is shuffled as well, if you overwrite an element, it gets overwritten in the original array, etc. Of course, some `List` operations aren't allowed on the wrapper, like adding or removing elements from the list, you can only read or overwrite the elements.

   Note that the list wrapper doesn't extend `ArrayList` - it's a different kind of object. `ArrayList`s have their own, internal array, in which they store their elements, and are able to resize the internal arrays etc. The wrapper doesn't have its own internal array, it only propagates operations to the array given to it.
2. On the other hand, if you subsequently create a new array as

   ```
   new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(ia))
   ```

   then you create new `ArrayList`, which is a full, independent copy of the original one. Although here you create the wrapper using `Arrays.asList` as well, it is used only during the construction of the new `ArrayList` and is garbage-collected afterwards. The structure of this new `ArrayList` is completely independent of the original array. It contains the same elements (both the original array and this new `ArrayList` reference the same integers in memory), but it creates a new, internal array, that holds the references. So when you shuffle it, add, remove elements etc., the original array is unchanged.

Comment: @Dineshkumar A wrapper is a design pattern that translates one interface for a class into another interface. See [the wrapper pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) article. | Where do you need to upcast? I'd suggest to use `List<Integer>` for your variable types (or method arguments etc.). This makes your code more generic and you can easily switch to another `List` implementation as needed, without having to rewrite a lot of code.

Comment: That is a good explanation. Extending this question, the Arrays.asList() method also takes varargs. If I pass specific values, say I do: Arrays.asList(1,3,5) twice, will it return the same List?

Answer (score 31):

Well, this is because `ArrayList` resulting from `Arrays.asList()` is not of the type `java.util.ArrayList`.

`Arrays.asList()` creates an `ArrayList` of type `java.util.Arrays$ArrayList` which does not extend `java.util.ArrayList`, but only extends `java.util.AbstractList`.

Comment: I think this is the root of many evils.

Answer (score 9):

```
List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(ia));  //copy
```

In this case, `list1` is of type `ArrayList`.

```
List<Integer> list2 = Arrays.asList(ia);
```

Here, the list is returned as a `List` view, meaning it has only the methods attached to that interface. Hence why some methods are not allowed on `list2`.

```
ArrayList<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(ia));
```

Here, you *are* creating a new `ArrayList`. You're simply passing it a value in the constructor. This is not an example of casting. In casting, it might look more like this:

```
ArrayList list1 = (ArrayList)Arrays.asList(ia);
```

Answer (score 5):

First of all, the Arrays class is a utility class which contains a number of utility methods to operate on Arrays (thanks to the Arrays class. Otherwise, we would have needed to create our own methods to act on Array objects)

#### asList() method:

1. `asList` method is one of the utility methods of `Array` class, it is a static method that's why we can call this method by its class name (like `Arrays.asList(T...a)` )
2. Now here is the twist. Please note that this method doesn't create new `ArrayList` object. It just returns a List reference to an existing `Array` object (so now after using `asList` method, two references to existing `Array` object gets created)
3. and this is the reason. All methods that operate on `List` object, may *not* work on this Array object using the `List` reference. Like
   for example, `Array`s size is fixed in length, hence you obviously can not add or remove elements from `Array` object using this `List` reference (like `list.add(10)` or `list.remove(10);`. Else it will throw UnsupportedOperationException).
4. any change you are doing using a list reference will be reflected in the exiting `Array`s object (as you are operating on an existing Array object by using a list reference)

In the first case, you are creating a new `Arraylist` object (in the second case, only a reference to existing Array object is created, but not a new `ArrayList` object), so now there are two different objects. One is the `Array` object and another is the `ArrayList` object and there isn't any connection between them (so changes in one object will not be reflected/affected in another object (that is, in case 2, `Array` and `Arraylist` are two different objects)

#### Case 1:

```
Integer [] ia = {1,2,3,4};
System.out.println("Array : "+Arrays.toString(ia));
List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(ia));  // new ArrayList object is created , no connection between existing Array Object
list1.add(5);
list1.add(6);
list1.remove(0);
list1.remove(0);
System.out.println("list1: " + list1);
System.out.println("Array: " + Arrays.toString(ia));
```

#### Case 2:

```
Integer [] ia = {1,2,3,4};
System.out.println("Array: " + Arrays.toString(ia));
List<Integer> list2 = Arrays.asList(ia); // Creates only a (new) List reference to the existing Array object (and NOT a new ArrayList Object)
//  list2.add(5); // It will throw java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException - invalid operation (as Array size is fixed)
list2.set(0,10);  // Making changes in the existing Array object using the List reference - valid 
list2.set(1,11); 
ia[2]=12;     // Making changes in the existing Array object using the Array reference - valid
System.out.println("list2: " + list2);
System.out.println("Array: " + Arrays.toString(ia));
```

Answer (score 4):

An explanation with documentation references would be better for someone looking for answer.

#### 1. [java.util.Arrays](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Arrays.java#Arrays)

- This is a utility class with bunch of static methods to operate on given array
- [asList](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Arrays.java#Arrays.asList%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) is one such static method that takes input array and returns an object of **java.util.Arrays.ArrayList** which is a static nested class that extends AbstractList<E> which in turn implements List interface.
- So Arrays.asList(inarray) returns a List wrapper around the input array, but this wrapper is **java.util.Arrays.ArrayList and not java.util.ArrayList** and it refers to the same array, so adding more elements to the List wrapped array would affect the original one too and also we cannot change the length.

#### 2. [java.util.ArrayList](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList)

- ArrayList has a bunch of overloaded constructors

  ```
   public ArrayList() - // Returns arraylist with default capacity 10

   public ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c)

   public ArrayList(int initialCapacity)
  ```
- So when we pass the Arrays.asList returned object, i.e., List(AbstractList) to the second constructor above, it will create a new dynamic array (this array size increases as we add more elements than its capacity and also the new elements will not affect the original array) shallow copying the original array ([shallow copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38641495/java-implement-deep-and-shallow-copy-of-an-array) means it copies over the references only and does not create a new set of same objects as in original array)

Answer (score 4):

```
String names[] = new String[]{"Avinash","Amol","John","Peter"};
java.util.List<String> namesList = Arrays.asList(names);
```

or

```
String names[] = new String[]{"Avinash","Amol","John","Peter"};
java.util.List<String> temp = Arrays.asList(names);
```

The above statement adds the wrapper on the input array. So the methods like *add* and *remove* will not be applicable on the list reference object 'namesList'.

If you try to add an element in the existing array/list then you will get "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException".

The above operation is readonly or viewonly. 
We can not perform add or remove operation in list object.

But

```
String names[] = new String[]{"Avinash","Amol","John","Peter"};
java.util.ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(names));
```

or

```
String names[] = new String[]{"Avinash","Amol","John","Peter"};
java.util.List<String> listObject = Arrays.asList(names);
java.util.ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>(listObject);
```

In the above statement you have created a concrete instance of an ArrayList class and passed a list as a parameter.

In this case, methods *add* and *remove* will work properly as both methods are from ArrayList class, so here we won't get any UnSupportedOperationException.
Changes made in the Arraylist object (method add or remove an element in/from an arraylist) will get not reflect in to the original *java.util.List object*.

```
String names[] = new String[] {
    "Avinash",
    "Amol",
    "John",
    "Peter"
};

java.util.List < String > listObject = Arrays.asList(names);
java.util.ArrayList < String > list1 = new ArrayList < > (listObject);
for (String string: list1) {
    System.out.print("   " + string);
}
list1.add("Alex"); // Added without any exception
list1.remove("Avinash"); // Added without any exception will not make any changes in original list in this case temp object.


for (String string: list1) {
    System.out.print("   " + string);
}
String existingNames[] = new String[] {
    "Avinash",
    "Amol",
    "John",
    "Peter"
};
java.util.List < String > namesList = Arrays.asList(names);
namesList.add("Bob"); // UnsupportedOperationException occur
namesList.remove("Avinash"); // UnsupportedOperationException
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that, in Java 8, 'ia' above must be Integer[] and not int[]. Arrays.asList() of an int array returns a list with a single element. When using the OP's code snippet, the compiler will catch the issue, but some methods (e.g., *Collections.shuffle()*) will silently fail to do what you expect.

Comment: I faced this compiler  issue when i did ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(a)); where a was an int[]. My al got just single element that too when printed looked garbage. What is that element ? And how does it happen to come there? I faced this issue in Java 7

Comment: @JyotsanaNandwani Pls check my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54105519/1163607

Answer (score 2):

Many people have answered the mechanical details already, but it's worth noting:
This is a poor design choice, by Java.

Java's `asList` method is documented as "Returns a *fixed-size* list...".  If you take its result and call (say) the `.add` method, it throws an `UnsupportedOperationException`.  This is unintuitive behavior!  If a method says it returns a `List`, the standard expectation is that it returns an object which supports the methods of interface `List`.  A developer shouldn't have to memorize *which* of the umpteen `util.List` methods create `List`s that don't actually support all the `List` methods.

If they had named the method `asImmutableList`, it would make sense.  Or if they just had the method return an actual `List` (and copy the backing array), it would make sense.  They decided to favor both runtime-performance *and* short names, at the expense of violating both the [principle of least astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) and the good object-oriented practice of avoiding `UnsupportedOperationException`s.

(Also, the designers might have made a `interface ImmutableList`, to avoid a plethora of `UnsupportedOperationException`s.)

Answer (score 1):

```
package com.copy;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class CopyArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list1, list2 = null;
        Integer[] intarr = { 3, 4, 2, 1 };
        list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(intarr));
        list1.add(30);
        list2 = Arrays.asList(intarr);
        // list2.add(40); Here, we can't modify the existing list,because it's a wrapper
        System.out.println("List1");
        Iterator<Integer> itr1 = list1.iterator();
        while (itr1.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(itr1.next());
        }
        System.out.println("List2");
        Iterator<Integer> itr2 = list2.iterator();
        while (itr2.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(itr2.next());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Arrays.asList()`

This method returns its own implementation of List. It takes an array as an argument and builds methods and attributes on top of it, since it is not copying any data from an array but using the original array this causes alteration in original array when you modify list returned by the `Arrays.asList()` method.

On the other hand, `ArrayList(Arrays.asList());`
is a constructor of `ArrayList` class which takes a list as argument and returns an `ArrayList` that is independent of list, i.e., `Arrays.asList()` in this case passed as an argument.

That is why you see these results.

Answer (score 0):

```
1.List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(ia));  //copy
2.List<Integer> list2 = Arrays.asList(ia);
```

In line 2, `Arrays.asList(ia)` returns a `List` reference of inner class object defined within `Arrays`, which is also called `ArrayList` but is private and only extends `AbstractList`. This means what returned from `Arrays.asList(ia)` is a class object different from what  you get from `new ArrayList<Integer>`.

You cannot use some operations to line 2 because the inner private class within `Arrays` does not provide those methods.

Take a look at this link and see what you can do with the private inner class:
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Arrays.java#Arrays.ArrayList

Line 1 creates a new `ArrayList` object copying elements from what you get from line 2. So you can do whatever you want since `java.util.ArrayList` provides all those methods.

Answer (score 0):

Summary of the difference -

When a list is created without using the *new*, the operator Arrays.asList() method returns a *wrapper* which means:

1. you can perform an add/update operation.
2. the changes done in the original array will be reflected to List as well and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

In response to some comments asking questions about the behaviour of [Arrays.asList()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-) since Java 8:

```
    int[] arr1 = {1,2,3};
    /* 
       Arrays are objects in Java, internally int[] will be represented by 
       an Integer Array object which when printed on console shall output
       a pattern such as 
       [I@address for 1-dim int array,
       [[I@address for 2-dim int array, 
       [[F@address for 2-dim float array etc. 
   */
    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(arr1)); 

    /* 
       The line below results in Compile time error as Arrays.asList(int[] array)
       returns List<int[]>. The returned list contains only one element 
       and that is the int[] {1,2,3} 
    */
    // List<Integer> list1 = Arrays.asList(arr1);

    /* 
       Arrays.asList(arr1) is  Arrays$ArrayList object whose only element is int[] array
       so the line below prints [[I@...], where [I@... is the array object.
    */
    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(arr1)); 

    /* 
     This prints [I@..., the actual array object stored as single element 
     in the Arrays$ArrayList object. 
    */
    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(arr1).get(0));

    // prints the contents of array [1,2,3]
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Arrays.asList(arr1).get(0)));

    Integer[] arr2 = {1,2,3};
    /* 
     Arrays.asList(arr) is  Arrays$ArrayList object which is 
     a wrapper list object containing three elements 1,2,3.
     Technically, it is pointing to the original Integer[] array 
    */
    List<Integer> list2 = Arrays.asList(arr2);

    // prints the contents of list [1,2,3]
    System.out.println(list2);
```