# How to resolve this nullpointer exception SUNSHINE APP. SIMPLE? onPostExecute

Tags: java, android, json

I have been following the course on udacity and have nearly finished lesson 2. The program should be updating the list view with the now parsed data on the `JSON`. Except when the following code is added the program crashes:

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {
        if (result != null) {
            forecastAdapter.clear();
            for (String dayForecastStr : result) {
                forecastAdapter.add(dayForecastStr);
            }
        }
    }
```

If that code is not there the program runs as usual and logs the results of the json parse. Others have suggested to

> "Make sure you don't redefine the mForecastAdapter in "onCreateView"
>   and only have : mForecastAdapter = new ArrayAdapter"

I'm unsure about how to go ahead of this. I already have `mForecastAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>` at the head of my class. And the rest of the code on the oncreateview is just loading the array into the listview.

The error log I currently have is:

> 11-05 19:29:00.049  20310-20553/com.example.jeremy.sunshine
>   V/FetchWeatherTask﹕ Forecast entry:               Wed, Nov 5 - Clear -
>   7/7
>       11-05 19:29:00.049  20310-20553/com.example.jeremy.sunshine V/FetchWeatherTask﹕ Forecast entry:     Thu, Nov 6 - Rain - 12/9
>        11-05 19:29:00.049  20310-20553/com.example.jeremy.sunshine V/FetchWeatherTask﹕ Forecast entry: Fri, Nov 7 - Rain - 12/10
>        11-05 19:29:00.049  20310-20553/com.example.jeremy.sunshine V/FetchWeatherTask﹕ Forecast entry: Sat,   Nov 8 - Rain - 12/11
>       11-05 19:29:00.049  20310-20553/com.example.jeremy.sunshine V/FetchWeatherTask﹕ Forecast entry: Sun, Nov 9 - Rain - 15/11 11-05
>   19:29:00.049  20310-20553/com.example.jeremy.sunshine
>   V/FetchWeatherTask﹕ Forecast entry: Mon, Nov 10 - Clear - 15/12 11-05
>   19:29:00.049  20310-20553/com.example.jeremy.sunshine
>   V/FetchWeatherTask﹕ Forecast entry: Tue, Nov 11 - Clear - 15/11
>       11-05 19:29:00.049  20310-20310/com.example.jeremy.sunshine D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
>       11-05 19:29:00.049  20310-20310/com.example.jeremy.sunshine W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception
>   (group=0x415c5db8) 11-05 19:29:00.049 
>   20310-20310/com.example.jeremy.sunshine E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.jeremy.sunshine, PID: 20310
>       java.lang.NullPointerException
>               at com.example.jeremy.sunshine.ForecastFragment$FetchWeatherTask.onPostExecute(ForecastFragment.java:305)
>               at com.example.jeremy.sunshine.ForecastFragment$FetchWeatherTask.onPostExecute(ForecastFragment.java:108)
>               at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
>               at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
>               at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

My whole class can be seen here:

As this is my first android project I'm baffled to why this won't work. I presume its something I must be overlooking.http://pastebin.com/x3rcqbdS

Comment: [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: The post execute is checking for a null pointer already is that not sufficient?

Comment: You check for `result` nullity. Means that `forecastAdapter` is null, I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you initialize your `forecastAdapter` in `onCreateView` with the following code:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> forecastAdapter =
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(
```

You are creating a new instance of `forecastAdapter` that is only within the scope of `onCreateView`. Then when you go to use your `forecastAdapter` in `onPostExecute` the `forecastAdapter` that is within the scope of `onPostExecute` is null because it was never initialized, the other instance was though (as Elliott Frisch mentioned, who just deleted his answer).

You should be able to just delete the `ArrayAdapter<String>` from your `onCreateView` adapter and it will work.

Comment: You were right that part did have to go but I also needed to change  the array into a public instead of private! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. The solution is that you must not be adding list to the `mForecastAdapter` because according to the old code we add `String[]` rather than the `weekForecast` list. So make sure that this line is proper:

```
mForecastAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item_forecast, R.id.list_item_forecast_textview,weekForecast);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had had this problem before.
The array adapter is not null as I can access its count, but I can't clear it or add elements to it. This is because the way I have initialised my array adapter in onCreateView() method. I passed it the last argument as "Arrays.asList(my_array_of_strings)"

```
String[] data = {
            "Mon 6/23 - Sunny - 31/17",
            "Tue 6/24 - Foggy - 21/8",
            "Wed 6/25 - Cloudy - 22/17",
            "Thurs 6/26 - Rainy - 18/11",
            "Fri 6/27 - Foggy - 21/10",
            "Sat 6/28 - TRAPPED IN WEATHERSTATION - 23/18",
            "Sun 6/29 - Sunny - 20/7"
    };

arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item_forecast,
            R.id.list_item_forecast_textview, Arrays.asList(data));
```

while the last argument should be "new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(my_array_of_strings))"

```
String[] data = {
            "Mon 6/23 - Sunny - 31/17",
            "Tue 6/24 - Foggy - 21/8",
            "Wed 6/25 - Cloudy - 22/17",
            "Thurs 6/26 - Rainy - 18/11",
            "Fri 6/27 - Foggy - 21/10",
            "Sat 6/28 - TRAPPED IN WEATHERSTATION - 23/18",
            "Sun 6/29 - Sunny - 20/7"
    };
    List<String> weekForecast = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(data));

    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item_forecast,
            R.id.list_item_forecast_textview, weekForecast);
```

this is because the difference between Arrays.asList(array) and new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(array)) as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16748030/difference-between-arrays-aslistarray-vs-new-arraylistintegerarrays-aslist) .