# Enum List Removal Issue

Tags: java, list, enums, enumeration

Can anyone help me to get the issue ?

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    List<TestEnum> list1 = new ArrayList<TestEnum>();
    list1.add(TestEnum.ONE);
    list1.add(TestEnum.TWO);
    list1.add(TestEnum.THREE);

    System.out.println(list1);
    System.out.println(list1.remove(TestEnum.TWO));
    System.out.println(list1);

    System.out.println("-----------------------");

    TestEnum[] xx = new TestEnum[]{TestEnum.ONE, TestEnum.TWO, TestEnum.THREE};
    List<TestEnum> list2 = Arrays.asList(xx);

    System.out.println(list2);
    System.out.println(list2.remove(TestEnum.TWO));
    System.out.println(list2);
}
```

---

Below is the Result -

```
[ONE, TWO, THREE]
true
[ONE, THREE]
-----------------------
[ONE, TWO, THREE]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
at java.util.AbstractList.remove(Unknown Source)
at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.remove(Unknown Source)
at java.util.AbstractCollection.remove(Unknown Source)
at Test.main(Test.java:24)
```

Please help  - Why this is happening, I have also checked hashcode ?

Comment: list returned by `Arrays.asList()` doesn't support `.remove()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between Arrays.asList(array) vs new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(ia)) in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16748030/difference-between-arrays-aslistarray-vs-new-arraylistintegerarrays-aslist)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

List returned by `Arrays.asList()` has fixed size--the size of array it is backed by. It doesn't support operations that may lead to size change: `add()`, `addAll()`, `remove()`, `removeAll()`, `retainAll()`, `clear()`.

You may use the following idiom to create a list of modifiable size:

```
List<TestEnum> = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(xx));
```

this will create an ordinary `ArrayList` initialized by elements copied from result of `Arrays.asList()`.

Answer (score 2):

`Arrays.asList` returns instance of immutable list, on which `remove` cannot be called. You have to wrap it in new list

`new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(xx))`

Comment: `Arrays.asList()` is not immutable since you can modify it calling `.set()`

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look into the method `asList` of the `Arrays` class, you will see that a `new ArrayList<>()` is returned. But the object which is instantied there is another private `ArrayList` class from inside the `Arrays` class. This class extends `AbstractList` like the normal `ArrayList` does, but it does not override the `remove` method. And this is the original implementation of the `remove` method.

```
/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 *
 * <p>This implementation always throws an
 * {@code UnsupportedOperationException}.
 *
 * @throws UnsupportedOperationException {@inheritDoc}
 * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException     {@inheritDoc}
 */
public E remove(int index) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Arrays.asList` returns a special `ArrayList` object which does not support any operation which would modify it's size.

From the documentation of this method:

> This method also provides a convenient way to create a fixed-size list
>   initialized to contain several elements.

Comment: it actually does support modification methods, but only those that don't change the size.