# Combining three int arrays into one, Java

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to write a merge method that takes three arrays and moves them into one. I'm quite new to java and the website where I'm submitting this code isn't very helpful with pointing out my error

```
static int[] mergeArrays(int[] a1, int[] a2, int[] a3) {

int[] answer = new int[a1.length + a2.length + a3.length];
int i,j,k;
for (i = 0; i < a1.length; i++)
    answer[i] = a1[i];

for (j = 0; j < a2.length; j++)
    answer[i++] = a2[j];

for (k = 0; k < a3.length; k++)
    answer[i++] = a3[k];

return answer;
}
```

Comment: Does it give you *any* indication as to what the problem is? As far as I can see that works (provided you don't need to handle null arguments, which doesn't really make sense anyway).

Comment: It doesn't, however this brings up nearly 30 errors at runtime in an unviewable/unaccessable main method.

Comment: So... where's the code for your main method?

Comment: The main method is already completed and I'm unable to see it... not very useful. 

I'm going to rewrite this and try to sort the arrays, so my result looks like {a1[0], a1[1], a1[2] a2[0 ....... etc]

Comment: You could specify the platform you are submitting to and the output you are getting. It could be useful.

Comment: Finally got it, had an extra } bracket at the end and didn't even notice

Comment: Your method works.

Answer (score 2):

I do not see any benefit in writing a method that merges exactly three arrays. Please consider this more flexible signature:

```
public static int[] merge(int[]... intArrays);
```

Also low level loops and index manipulation should be avoided, Java 8 comes to help!

```
public static int[] merge(int[]... intArrays) {
    return Arrays.stream(intArrays)
            .flatMapToInt(i -> Arrays.stream(i))
            .toArray();
}
```

This is very concise, has no code duplication, no low level code and can even to be done in a parallel stream if arrays are large or many.

Answer (score 0):

`List<Integer> mergedArray = Arrays.asList(array1);` //will give you first list.

```
mergedArray.addAll(Arrays.asList(array2));
mergedArray.addAll(Arrays.asList(array3));
```

Comment: This won't work since `Arrays.asList()` method returns a fixed-size list. So `.addAll()` method will throw an Exception

Comment: You can take a look at this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16748030/difference-between-arrays-aslistarray-vs-new-arraylistintegerarrays-aslist)