# Cannot add element to ObservableList (UnsupportedOperationException) in JavaFX

Tags: java, arrays, list, javafx

**Initial Starting Point**

I have an existing `List` of 1000 `Person` objects which I would like to insert an `Extractor` to listen for property changes within any `Person` objects (this `ObservableList` will be later attached to a `TableView`).

So my code would be like:

```
ObservableList<Person> observablePersons = FXCollections.observableList(personlist,
    personextractor);
```

**Error Message**

But when I try to add a new person objects to this ObservableList **observablePersons**, I run into this error:

```
run:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:148)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper.doAdd(ObservableListWrapper.java:101)
    at javafx.collections.ModifiableObservableListBase.add(ModifiableObservableListBase.java:151)
    at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:108)
    at test.listchangelistener.listChangeDemo.main(listChangeDemo.java:72)
Java Result: 1
```

Could you please tell me why would I come across this error message? My java version is **jdk1.8.0_91 (32-Bit)**

*Person Class*

```
package test.listchangelistener;

import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

class Person {

    private final IntegerProperty age = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
    private final StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public Person(String name, Integer age) {
        setName(name);
        setAge(age);
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age.get();
    }

    public final void setAge(int value) {
        age.set(value);
    }

    public IntegerProperty ageProperty() {
        return age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name.get();
    }

    public final void setName(String value) {
        name.set(value);
    }

    public StringProperty nameProperty() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person{" + "age=" + age.get() + ", name=" + name.get() + '}';
    }

}
```

*Test Code*

```
package test.listchangelistener;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import javafx.beans.Observable;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.util.Callback;


public class listChangeDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Person p1 = new Person("Ted", 26);
        Person p2 = new Person("Anne", 19);

        // just a simple list
        List<Person> persons = Arrays.asList(p1, p2);

        // extractor to observe change of person properties
        Callback<Person, Observable[]> extractor = (Person p) -> {
            return new Observable[]{
                p.ageProperty(),
                p.nameProperty()
            };
        };

        // make list observable and attach extractor
        ObservableList<Person> observablePersons = FXCollections.observableList(persons, extractor);

        // create listchangeListener for observableList
        ListChangeListener listener = (ListChangeListener) (ListChangeListener.Change c) -> {
            while (c.next()) {
                if (c.wasAdded()) {
                    System.out.println("these were added: ");

                    List addedSubList = c.getAddedSubList();
                    addedSubList.forEach((Object t) -> {
                        System.out.println("added Person: " + t);
                    });
                } else if (c.wasRemoved()) {
                    System.out.println("these were removed");

                    List removedSubList = c.getRemoved();
                    removedSubList.forEach((Object t) -> {
                        System.out.println("removed Person: " + t);
                    });

                } else if (c.wasUpdated()) {
                    System.out.println("these were updated");

                    System.out.println("Updated elements are: "
                            + c.getList().subList(c.getFrom(), c.getTo()));
                }
            }
        };

        // attach listchangeListener to observableList
        observablePersons.addListener(listener);

        // testing changes
        observablePersons.add(new Person("Siegfried", 10));

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this question should be marked as a duplicate. While the underlying problem ends up being the same, the situations are different. In my opinion, the addition of observable list in this case makes it a unique question

Answer (score 13):

The problem is coming from the creation of your backing `List`:

```
List<Person> persons = Arrays.asList(p1, p2);
```

If you take a look on the [javadoc of Arrays.asList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29):

> Returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array.

On a closer look you got an [UnsupportedOperationException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/UnsupportedOperationException.html) because [List.add()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add-int-E-) is an **optional operation**:

> Throws:
>       UnsupportedOperationException - if the add operation is not supported by this list.

You can update the creation of the backing list as:

```
List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>(Arrays.asList(p1, p2));
```

The difference is that the returned `ArrayList` is an exact, independent copy of the passed one, therefore the restriction described above is not valid anymore in this case.

You can also take a look on this question which explaines this topic in depths:

[Difference between Arrays.asList(array) vs new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(ia)) in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16748030/difference-between-arrays-aslistarray-vs-new-arraylistintegerarrays-aslist)

Comment: Hi DVarga! Thanks so much for your fast reply! Yes, I totally overlooked the restriction of the Arrays.asList(). That was so stupid of me. Anyways thanks a ton!