# Benefits of creating a List using Arrays.asList()

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist

Referring to [Difference between Arrays.asList(array) vs new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(ia)) in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16748030/difference-between-arrays-aslistarray-vs-new-arraylistintegerarrays-aslist)
I was curious as in what's the exact purpose of `Arrays.asList()` method.

When we create a new `List` from it, say for example -

```
Integer[] I = new Integer[] { new Integer(1), new Integer(2), new Integer(3) };
List<Integer> list1 = Arrays.asList(I);
List<Integer> list2 = ((List<Integer>) Arrays.asList(I));
```

We cannot perform most of the the regular operations on it like `.add()`, `.remove()`. Thus, I was not able add an iterator to it to avoid [concurrent modification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223918/iterating-through-a-collection-avoiding-concurrentmodificationexception-when-re).

Oracle docs state

> public static  List asList(T... a)
>
> Returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array. (Changes to
>   the returned list "write through" to the array.) This method acts as
>   bridge between array-based and collection-based APIs, in combination
>   with Collection.toArray(). The returned list is serializable and
>   implements RandomAccess.

It works well with creating a new `List`. `List<Integer> list3 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(I));`

So, why this and what are its advantages and disadvantages?

Comment: One is a `List` **view** of an array. The other is a copy of an array into an entirely separate `List`. You're comparing [apples and oranges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apples_and_oranges).

Comment: It's the shortest way to get a list. `Arrays.asList("Alpha", "Beta")`. And it is explicitly backed by the array you give it - you can use it to actually modify an array if that's what you need.

Comment: If you already have an `Integer[]`, then there's probably not a huge difference between Arrays.asList and ArrayList (unless you need the ArrayList's functionality, of course). But if you don't, then `List<Integer> list1 = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3)` is pretty convenient.

Comment: It's useful for creating and populating a list in a single line. `private static final List<String> VALID_INPUTS = Arrays.asList("Cat","Dog","Mouse");`

Answer (score 1):

Not being able to call add, remove, etc is the exact difference. If you don't need those methods, Arrays.asList gives you a perfectly fine view of the array as a List (for APIs that take collections rather than arrays). If you need to change the "shape" of the list, then new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(myArray)) is the way to go.