# What is the return type of Arrays.asList?

Tags: java, collections

I read this post:
[Difference between Arrays.asList(array) vs new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(ia)) in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16748030/difference-between-arrays-aslistarray-vs-new-arraylistintegerarrays-aslist)

and I have a question about it. 
I look at the line:

```
List<Integer> list2 = Arrays.asList(ia)
```

and still there is a line saying:

> Of course, some List operations aren't allowed on the wrapper, like
>   adding or removing elements from the list, you can only read or
>   overwrite the elements.

If list2 has a reference of List Interface, I expect it to implement ALL methods included in List interface in Java. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html.

> add(int index, E element)

and

> remove(int index)

show in List interface, so how is it possible that they are not implemented in list2?

I would have expected that `list2` is a **List**; and thus I could call **all** methods belonging to the List interface?! So why are there exceptions thrown when calling `add()` or `remove()`?

Comment: Part of the specification of [`List#add`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add(E)) is "throws [`UnsupportedOperationException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/UnsupportedOperationException.html) if the add operation is not supported by this list". The list implementation returned by `Arrays.asList` conforms to the interface's specification by throwing such an exception.

Comment: check that `System.out.print(list2)`

Comment: These methods are of course implemented, but they will throw `UnsupportedOperationException` when you call them.

Comment: Refer java.util.Arrays.ArrayList<E> which is return by Arrays.asList().
It will answer your question.

Comment: If you read the documentation more carefully, you'll see that `add()` and `remove()` are *optional operations* that may be unsupported by implementing classes. They'll have **some** implementation, but that could be to throw an exception.

Comment: "aren't allowed" is not the same as "not implemented"

Comment: I think the only problem with your question is the wording. It actually gives "food for thought"; and I never questioned before on the exact behavior of the lists returned by that call. On the other hand, that tells you one thing: you can use this method for 10+ years without worrying that `remove()` will throw at you. Because the normal use case is to not remove something from such a list ;-)

Answer (score 6):

There is a subtle detail here that is probably easy to miss:

The [Arrays.asList()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)) javadoc briefly mentions:

> Returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array.

In other words: yes, you receive something that says "I am a List"; but in fact, the underlying implementation gives you something we would call an *structurally immutable* list object. Thus all the methods that would change the *structure* of that specific list ... are "disabled" (by throwing exceptions at the call). You can still call `set()` though to **change** elements within that list.

Long story short: the *purpose* of this method is **not** to give you a fully List-supporting object. The purpose of this method is to allow you to quickly create a **fixed** "list" of objects.

And more of personal opinion: I agree, this is actually not "consistent". I would have expected that either a completely **immutable** list would be returned; instead of some "half-baked" "structurally immutable".

Comment: @Tom Kudos. Actually I wasnt aware of that. Thanks for pointing this out ... I updated my answer accordingly. And for the record: imho, this behavior is very surprising ... thus: not how I would have done it.

Comment: Well it kinda makes sense that it is only structural immutable, because someone still can have a reference to the underlying array and prefer to use that next to the wrapped list reference. Thus altering the size would result in a different array reference for the list and one can't use both anymore (the original array and the list for the same data), although I don't know why one should want to do that :D.

Comment: I agree; I ended up writing my own wrappers for that purpose; as we arent using guava in our environment ... anyway: any other hints what I could do to get my answer into the "upvote worthy" side of things?

Comment: The mutable wrapper returned by `Arrays.asList()` is actually quite useful for adapting to list-mutating helpers that are not available for simple arrays, like those in the `Collections` class.

Answer (score 1):

It returns `java.util.Arrays.ArrayList` which is a *fixed-size list*, not `java.util.ArrayList`.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays.asList(ia) method returns an object from a class that extends AbstractList class and AbstractList class implements List interface.
The name of this class that extends AbstractList is unfortunately ArrayList (the same name with the public ArrayList that we all know-java.util.ArrayList). But be careful. This class is an **inner** private static class of class Arrays an instance of which is created and returned by Arrays.asList method. Check the source code of class Arrays [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/be44bff34df4/src/share/classes/java/util/Arrays.java). So the path of this inner private static class is java.util.Arrays.ArrayList and NOT java.util.ArrayList. These are different classes despite having the same name and we can not create java.util.Arrays.ArrayList with new operator because is private. Only as a return from Arrays method like Arrays.asList method.

So as we see in Arrays source code the **inner** private static ArrayList class extends AbstractList class. AbstractList class is an abstract class that implements List interface. So it has to implement the two overloaded add methods from List interface. As we see in the source code of [AbstractList](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/AbstractList.java.html) class implements the add(int index,E element) method of List interface so that always returns UnsupportedOperationException.

```
public void add(int index, E element) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
```

Why? Be patient. The implementation of second add(E element) calls the previous add(int index,E element) with the first argument as the size of the list

```
public boolean add(E e) {
    add(size(), e);
    return true;
}
```

Proud to be here... we continue...
If a class that extends AbstractList (like inner ArrayList class of class Array) does not override the two inherited add methods then an UnsupportedOperationException will be returned whenever an add method is called.
Checking the source code of inner ArrayList class of class Array we find that there is not overridden method of add(int index, E element)...

So...quod erat demonstrandum

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the [Oracle Java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)) the documentation says that Arrays.asList(..) returns a fixed sized list. So it can be an implementation of the list interface that doesnt allow a change in the list size.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: For example you can implement a Class with List that throws a "NotImplementedException" on call of add or remove. So you can guarantee that the methods are not working

Answer (score 0):

The core of your question is:

> If list2 has a reference of `List` interface, I expect it to implement ALL methods included in `List` interface in Java.

You're right that anything that claims to be a `List` must contain an implementation of every method in the `List` interface. But the behaviour of that implementation is up to the implementation. A well behaved implementation should do what the JavaDoc for `List` does, but for example, `List.add()` notes:

> **Throws:**
>
> *UnsupportedOperationException* - if the add operation is not supported by this list

This is because it's often useful to have a `List` that you can iterate and read, but can't add to. Sometimes that's because it would be impossible -- for example, the list is a view onto a database for which you don't have write access. Sometimes it's because it would be illogical -- if you have a list of all four playing card suits, it makes no sense to change it. Sometimes it's just there to protect the programmer, in the same way as the `final` keyword stops you mistakenly modifying a variable. *Immutable* collections have huge benefits in security and in reliable multi-threading.

In this case, it's the first of these: it would be impossible within the constraints of what `Arrays.asList()` does. Because it's a a `List` view of an array, you can only do the same things you could do to an array. You can't change the length of an array, therefore you can't use `.add()` or `.remove()` on a `List` obtained from `Arrays.asList()`.

---

Some extra details, out of interest.

The Javadoc for `Arrays.asList()` doesn't tell you what the concrete class of the returned object will be; only its interface, `List`. That's because it's none of your business, and the implementation is free to change it.

However we can look at the source code, and see that `Arrays.java` contains `private static class ArrayList<E> extends AbstractList<E>`. This is what `Arrays.asList()` returns -- it's quite different and separate from `java.util.ArrayList`. It is private to `Arrays`, but another class can use it via the public interface `List`.

This implementation extends `AbstractList`, whose documentation includes:

> To implement an unmodifiable list, the programmer needs only to extend this class and provide implementations for the `get(int)` and `size()` methods.
>
> To implement a modifiable list, the programmer must additionally override the `set(int, E)` method (which otherwise throws an `UnsupportedOperationException`). If the list is variable-size the programmer must additionally override the `add(int, E)` and `remove(int)` methods.

The private `Arrays.ArrayList` does not extend `add()` or `remove()`.