# Initial size() of new ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

If I have the following:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("a","b","c"));
```

and call:

```
System.out.println(list.size());
```

It will print 3 as expected.

The `size()` method's code is just `return size;` where `size` is a `private int`.

So I'm wondering where it's actually setting that `size` variable.

I see it's calling the constructor `public ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c)`, which is fine, but when I debug into there, and hover over `c`, it already says `size = 3`.

So is it something in `Collection<? extends E> c` that's setting it to 3, *before* it gets to the `ArrayList` constructor?

Comment: Are you talking about http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java#l169?

Comment: What do you mean by `c == 3`? It's a Collection and not an int.

Comment: Wow, heavy downvotes. @MuratKaragöz when I debug to that constructor, and hover over `c`, it says `size = 3`. I thought this was a valid question.

Comment: @achAmháin That's a feature of your IDE showing the size.

Comment: *Wow, heavy downvotes* - also heavy upvotes. I would be content with a balance of 0 for a question you can answer simply by looking at the source

Comment: @TimCastelijns fair enough. I did look at the source code, but unfortunately I mis-read that specific line. But it answers my question.

Comment: @achAmháin maybe some IDE feature confused you? Something like the image I posted in my answer. It has happened to my from time to time ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens when you initialise the new ArrayList; in the constructor, you can see the size of the list is set to the size of the array you pass in:

```
/**
 * Constructs a list containing the elements of the specified
 * collection, in the order they are returned by the collection's
 * iterator.
 *
 * @param c the collection whose elements are to be placed into this list
 * @throws NullPointerException if the specified collection is null
 */
public ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c) {
    elementData = c.toArray();
    if ((size = elementData.length) != 0) {
        // c.toArray might (incorrectly) not return Object[] (see 6260652)
        if (elementData.getClass() != Object[].class)
            elementData = Arrays.copyOf(elementData, size, Object[].class);
    } else {
        // replace with empty array.
        this.elementData = EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA;
    }
}
```

so specifically  `if ((size = elementData.length) != 0)` sets the size (the private field you were talking about) to the length of the array passed into the constructor.

Comment: Thanks. Somehow I misread that line, so started looking for where it sets `size` elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

> *(...)* I'm wondering where it's actually setting that `size` variable

You called [this constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList-java.util.Collection-) of `ArrayList` in which [source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java#l167) we can see **`size = elementData.length;`**:

```
public ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c) {
    elementData = c.toArray();
    size = elementData.length; // <-- HERE
    if (elementData.getClass() != Object[].class)
        elementData = Arrays.copyOf(elementData, size, Object[].class);
}
```

So, once it is called [size()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#size--) ([source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java#l262)) that value is already set.

---

> when I debug into there, and hover over c, it already says size = 3

If you are referring to something like the image below... I think it might be some IDE feature (like in my case with IntelliJ IDEA) where it can infer the specific type of `c` (`List`) and compute its size.

[image]

---

> *(...)* is it something in `Collection<? extends E> c` that's setting it to 3, before it gets to the `ArrayLis`t constructor?

Remember `Arrays.asList` returns a [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) which is taken by the `ArrayList`'s constructor as a [`Collection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) which also has a [`size`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#size--) method. IDEs can use that for calculating the `size` value.

---

PS: The source code might slightly differ from specific jdk version to another version.

Answer (score 1):

It says it's already 3 because that is the size of the `Arrays.asList("a","b","c")` you pass as argument to `new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("a","b","c"));`.

From sources:

```
public ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c) {
    // c is already instantiated here 
    elementData = c.toArray();
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, the size is set on the next line in the constructor of the ArrayList.

```
if ((size = elementData.length) != 0) {
```

Details are well explained in this other SO thread 
[Details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16748030/difference-between-arrays-aslistarray-and-new-arraylistintegerarrays-aslist)