# Is it possible to create interface object?

Tags: java, class, collections, interface

```
String [] s = {"A","Z","B"};
List l  = Arrays.asList(s);
System.out.println(l);
```

I think it is not possible to create to create object of an interface.
So what is the meaning of the line

```
List l = Arrays.asList(s);
```

List is an interface so how we can create object of List?

Comment: List is the type for the reference variable and actual object is of a Concrete class implementing the List interface, this object is returned by the `Arrays.asList` method.

Comment: What do you think happens when you call `List l = new ArrayList()`? Are you creating List "interface object"? Now what if I create method like `ArrayList getList(){ return new ArrayList();}`, can we use it like `List l = getList();`?

Comment: BTW you may also be interested in [What does it mean to “program to an interface”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/383947). And don't EVER name your variable `l` (lower `L`) since in some fonts it is similar to `1` (one) which may cause unnecessary readability problems.

Comment: Also this may be related: [Difference between Arrays.asList(array) and new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(array))](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16748030)

Answer (score 0):

The Arrays.asList method actually returns a new ArrayList which is an implementation of List.

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that returned ArrayList isn't `java.util.ArrayList` but inner class inside `Arrays` which is also named `ArrayList`.

Answer (score -1):

You are creating a ArrayList, which is of type List.

Comment: add details to the answer which adds more value , the current one you can put as a comment rather than posting it as an answer