# How to remove all elements from List1 which are contained in List2 if List2 contains some of element which are not present in List1?

Tags: java, arraylist

For example,

```
List<String> list1 = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c","d");
List<String> list2 = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "e");
```

I want to remove all elements from list1 which are in list2, So what I did

```
list1.removeAll(List2);
return list1;
```

But I got UnsupportedOperationException.[image]
So is there something that I making mistake or is there any method to use for such scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an arraylist to perform `removeAll`. There's a difference between `Arrays.asList` and `new ArrayList`.

Refer - [Difference between Arrays.asList(array) and new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(array))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16748030/difference-between-arrays-aslistarray-and-new-arraylistintegerarrays-aslist)

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c","d"));
        List<String> list2 = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "e");
        list1.removeAll(list2);
        System.out.println(list1);
}
```

Output:

```
[c, d]
```